# Authorize.net report refresh rate?

Tags: authorize.net

I am submitting transactions, but don't see them in my authorize.net account. I am getting a response back from authorize.net. How long does it take for records to show in the reports section?

I am submitting to

```
https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll
```

Comment: Is the transaction successful? Are you in test mode?

Comment: I'm not in test mode, and am not using the developer site. The transactions are declined, but it should have a record of it being declined online.

Comment: Yes it should. So I tested mine, and I see them right away. I would call Authorize.net. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see those unsettled transactions in your Authorize.Net account, click "Search" in the top navigation and then "Unsettled Transactions" in the left navigation. Once they have been settled they will show up under the "Reports" section.

Answer (score 0):

They should show up immediately. New transactions show up in the unsettled transaction list, not in the settled batch reports. They don't show there until they are settled overnight.

Answer (score 0):

The **Report** section will only show you the details about the `"Settled Transactions"` and `"Decline Transactions"`.

When you submit the new transactions then then you can see those transactions in the "Unsettled Transactions". Authorize.net don't quickly Settled Transactions, it takes some time (I think 24 hours, please check) to get the transaction settled.

[image]

[image]